# What is causing my image nodes to be responsive to clicks when only the lastChild node is supposed to?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a mini javascript finding the difference game. Essentially, there are two divs and images of smileys in each div, and there will always ben an extra smiley on the left div. And you have to click on that extra div to the left. If clicked on anywhere else or any other faces, it should alert the user and end the game.

So, I have looked on w3schools and also on Stackoverflow but I haven't yet found anything that is helping.

The problem I am having here is that my code is breaking. Instead of only detecting `.onclick` on the lastChild of the left div. It is detecting on all the faces and therefore, adding 5 smileys every time.

What am I doing wrong here? I checked with the chrome debugging tools and couldn't find anything either.

Also, when you click anywhere else on **leftSide** div, it is supposed to alert the user and end the game. After alerting, instead of ending the game and being non-responsive to further clicks, it is still responding to clicks and adding smileys.

All help are appreciated.

P.S. This is my second question on Stackoverflow. I apologize in advance if I am not formatting my questions the right way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <style>
      img {position:absolute;}

      #leftSide {
        position:absolute;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
      }

      #rightSide {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position:absolute;
        left: 500px;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body onload="generateFaces()">
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <p>
      Find and click on the extra smiling face on the left.
    </p>
    <div id="leftSide">

    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      var numberOfFaces = 5;
      var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
      var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
      var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

      function generateFaces() {
        for(var i=0; i<numberOfFaces; i++) {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";

          var y_position = Math.random() * 400;
          y_position = Math.floor(y_position);
          img.style.top = y_position + "px";

          var x_position = Math.random() * 400;
          x_position = Math.floor(x_position);
          img.style.left = x_position + "px";

          theLeftSide.appendChild(img);

          var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
          leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);

          theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

          theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick=
            function nextLevel(event) {


              while(theLeftSide.firstChild || theRightSide.firstChild) {
                theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
                theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
              };

              event.stopPropagation();
              numberOfFaces += 5;
              generateFaces();

            };

          theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
            alert("Game Over!");

            theBody.onclick = null;
            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
          };
        }

      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the winning onclick event to every item in the left side. If you just want to add it to the last item (the one which isn't going to be replicated) you need to tell the for loop so:

```
if (i === numberOfFaces - 1) {    
    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick=
        function nextLevel(event) {

          while(theLeftSide.firstChild || theRightSide.firstChild) {
            theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
            theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
          };
          event.stopPropagation();
          numberOfFaces += 5;
          generateFaces();

        };
}
```

Here's the fiddle (I changed `alert` for `console.log`, open the console to see the output): http://jsfiddle.net/zhv38xrp/1/

Comment: Wow, that was so quick. Thank you so much! It works. For some reason, I thought the "stopPropagation" method would do it for me. Newbie mistakes. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @developertenzin The `stopPropagation` method prevents de event to escalate upwards in the DOM tree, it doesn't affect the siblings of the element. Btw, happy to help, don't forget to mark the answer as correct ;)

Comment: Oh, thank you. Yes, I was just reading up on it. It makes a lot of sense now. Yes, I marked it correct, but since I am new to Stackoverflow, I need at least 15 points before my votes can go public. I have 13 right now. So, two more points and it should be public. If not, whenever I do get the 2 points, I will mark it correct if it isn't already. Thanks again for the help.